# Do I need to 'select' to wait for write availability when writing a socket from multiple threads?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, socketcan

I have code that writes to the same socket with multiple threads, like this, on Linux, which *seems* to be working in my development tests (pseudo-ish code):

```
Mutex theSocketMutex = ...;
int theSocket = ...;

void Thread () {
    while (...) {
        ...
        lock(theSocketMutex); 
        write(theSocket, ...);
        unlock(theSocketMutex);
        ...
    }
}
```

It's important that a single socket be used by all of these threads for writing (it's actually a SocketCAN socket, and I need to avoid the overhead of duplicate incoming frame processing on multiple sockets - I have one socket, one read thread, and multiple write threads).

The intended behavior is for the `write` to wait if hardware send buffers are full (which would be a few microseconds at most) rather than failing; but I'm not sure if the SocketCAN driver does this, or if it's guaranteed behavior of sockets in general, etc.

So my question is: Is the above sufficient, or do I also need to wait for the socket to be available for writing, e.g.:

```
void Thread () {
    while (...) {
        ...
        lock(theSocketMutex); 
        if (select(theSocket+1, NULL, &fdsetWrite, NULL, &timeout) != 1)
            ...; // fail
        else
            write(theSocket, ...);
        unlock(theSocketMutex); 
        ...
    }
}
```

It *is* working fine for my testing but I am not 100% confident in my tests here.

Comment: All that the `select` call will tell you is that you can write at least one byte to the descriptor without `write` (or `send`) blocking. It's not needed for writing to a descriptor from multiple threads, only the lock is.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that the `select` call will tell you is that you can write at least one byte to the descriptor without `write` (or `send`) blocking. It's not needed for writing to a descriptor from multiple threads, only the lock is.